# Reply to reviewers

Tags: peer-review

I recently submitted a manuscript and and a reviewer asked about sample size:

> The sample size is low to draw a strong conclusion to change the national policy, it is better to assess this trial as a pilot study. It is advisable to propose a multicentre trial to assess whether these findings are specific to this region. How the sample size was calculated and what is its external validation tool?

My manuscript is an observational reporting of a newly created hospital registry that included all patients with a particular disease. Since I was only reporting that data, no sample size calculation was done.

My question is how should I address that with the reviewer?

Comment: The sample size would be the total number of observed patients. What is the issue exactly?

Comment: Are you sure the reviewer understood that particular issue in the paper? The question is classic and you _should_ have "N = 4795" stated somewhere.

Comment: Yah the total number of participants was included in the study, this was his comment..: "The sample size is low to draw a strong conclusion to change the national policy, it is better to assess this trial as a pilot study. It is advisable to propose a multicentre trial to assess whether these findings are specific to this region . How the sample size was calculated and what is its external validation tool?"

Answer (score 4):

Based on your comment, it sounds like the reviewer is mainly suggesting a change of framing, about your discussion section and the generalizability or scope of your results.

I may not understand fully what you mean by "hospital registry." It sounds like a database or initiative set up at one hospital (or perhaps small hospital chain). My answer (and the reviewer's critique) would probably not apply if the registry actually has a large regional or nationwide scope.

When you introduce your data, you can describe your data in ways that help the reader evaluate this population's representativeness and generalizability. You can then *argue* in the discussion the extent to which your results would generalize. Between the initial data description and the discussion, you could find other data to help you "triangulate" your results and put your population in context.

- Does your region have a similar incidence of this disease as other places in the country? And what percentage of cases nationwide are there, compared to the number in your sample?
- Does your sample include all the presentations of this disease that are in the literature?
- Does the background information of these patients (distribution of age, gender, race/ethnicity, income/insurance status, comorbidity, risk factors) match the background information in the known literature on the disease?

  - If not, is this because the literature is too limited, or because your sample is not representative? It might be beneficial if your population actually overrepresents groups rarely afflicted with the disease.

Further, if you are aiming to change policy at hospitals across the country, then in some sense your N = 1. You should explain when introducing the data why the hospital (management structure, funding, etc.) is also representative.

If there is any comparable data you can systematically check your data against, that could be a useful new analysis for the end of your analysis/results section. As a check on the reliability of the data you have, you can also argue that your data in the registry is consistent with (or outperforms?) available data from the prior system. That is, do you have enough data so far to show that you're successfully describing what happens at that hospital?

It's also extraordinarily hard to get a policy or implementation that works in one place to work in another place, and so even if your work provides evidence toward a national policy, the reviewer may be right that, the "next steps" goal should aim for a slightly larger implementation. Thus, you may want to bring this up as a "limitation" to bring up in the discussion or conclusion section, along the lines of:

> While our study used the entire population of patients [in context], one may wonder if this approach will work beyond [context].

In light of these possibilities, embracing the reviewer's framing (this is a *success* as a pilot study, as opposed to a major study with limitations) may be useful, especially if you yourself are interested in working on scaling this up or implementing it more widely. Good luck!

Comment: Excellent response to a very vague question!